# WebDriver closing the popup

Tags: java, webdriver

I have web-driver test which is stuck because a pop-up window appears. How ca I close it in test?

Here is my code:

```
@Test
 public void canGoToSomePage() throws Exception {

 final WebDriver webDriver = getFireFoxDriver();
 webDriver.get(getRouteAbsolute("Application.index"));


 WebElement someElement = webDriver.findElement(By.id("some_id_here"));
 someElement.click();

 // HERE I GOT AUTHENTICATION POP-UP I WANT TO CLOSE


 assertNotNull(webDriver.findElement(By.id("some_2_id")));

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
 alert.accept();
```

I have never used alert before, I used to silent the pop up using JS before. You could do that too, but i guess Alert would be the first choice.

**EDIT#1**

Here is how to use Java script to silent the pop up. Note that it has to be executed BEFORE the click that causes the popup to show up. Based on whether your pop up is alert, confirm or prompt, you will have to use something like below.

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.alert = function(msg) { return true; }");
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }");
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.prompt = function(msg) { return true; }");
```

Comment: the problem is when popup is appears, it seems, the test stops and I futher line of code is not executing there.

Comment: That's bizarre, your test code should run even when the pop up occurs. I edited my answer to show how to 'silent' the pop up using Java script.

Comment: Just to clarify an old post: this is not "Java script". What he means is "JavaScript" (as a single word). "Java is to JavaScript what ham is to hamster."

Comment: @nilesh I am also encountering the same problem. Stuck on Internet Explorer after executing the JavascriptExecuter to prompt the pop up. Once pop up appears, I am not able to click on it and further line of code is not executing

Comment: @ses Did you solved the issue? I am also experiencing the same issue. Could you please share what did you do to solve this?