# Test gets stuck when popup appears

Tags: java, webdriver

I have a web driver test which opens up a javascript confirmation on clicking a link, but the test is getting stuck once the confirmation appears. The remaining lines of code in the test does not execute until I manually click 'Ok' or 'Cancel' in the confirmation box. Please see the code below:

```
private WebDriver webDriver;

@Test
public void testClickButton() {

webDriver = getFireFoxDriver();

webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text() = 'Delete']")).click();

//JAVASCRIPT CONFIRMATION COMES UP AND THE TEST GETS STUCK!
//THE BELOW LINE DOES NOT EXECUTE UNTIL THE CONFIRMATION IS MANUALLY CLICKED.
closePopUp();
}
```

I am facing this issue only on Firefox. The test runs fine on IE as well as Chrome.

A similar issue is posted @ [WebDriver closing the popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034497/webdriver-closing-the-popup) where silencing the pop up using java script is suggested as a work around. This looks like an interesting way to get around the issue, however I would like to know whether there is any alternative to it without using java script. That might help me understand the root cause of this issue too. I tried adding wait of few milliseconds after the link click, but it did not help. Did quite a bit of googling too, which didn't help either.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you have against javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I am accepting a popup this way to close it:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

Its not java script but it works. You can also dismiss a popup.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tarken. This is exactly what I am doing in the 'closePopUp()' method call above. But the problem is that the 'closePopUp()' call does not get executed as the test gets stuck once the popup comes up.

Comment: Is your pop up a new window? Does your closePopUp know the driver? If yes can you post more of your code?

Comment: The popup is just a javascript confirmation for deleting a particular entity in the web application.  Please find the closePopUp method code below:  
  
    `public void closePopUp() {
    try {
    Alert alert = webDriver.switchTo().alert();
    System.out.println(alert.getText());
    alert.accept();
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException exc) {
    exc.printStackTrace();
    }` 
  
Please consider `webDriver` as a class level variable assigned to Firefox driver.

Comment: Are u sure both methods are working on the same webdriver? Can u check if your WebDriver in your ClosePopUp method knows where u are. With something like getCurrentUrl. I tried that and on closePopUp the webDriver throws a NullPointerException.

Comment: Thanks for your time Tarken. I have edited the Test code above to depict the `webDriver` class level variable.  Both methods are working on the same WebDriver instance. Infact, the above test works fine if `webDriver` is assigned to InternetExplorerDriver or ChromeDriver. It gets stuck only for FirefoxDriver. I cannot verify the webdriver in ClosePopUp method as the control never reaches there for Firefox.

Comment: Hmmmm strange. Your are using Selenium 2.16.1? Now I am just guessing if you insert  System.out.println("Something") that doesnt get called eihter? Do u have configured an implicit wait for your driver?

Comment: I was using Selenium 2.15.0. Since you mentioned it, I upgraded Selenium to 2.16.1 and reran the test, however the issue still persists. You are right, none of the code in the closePopUp method is called once the confirmation comes up. I have configured an implicit wait of 5secs in the webdriver.

Comment: This looks like your problem somehow but it should be fixed.
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1305
Maybe you should open a new issue there. Sorry I am out of ideas. One last idea try using cssSelector or something else to find the element to click on. sry

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer Tarken. I tried using [Actions](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions) to click on the **Delete** link and I see that sometimes the test runs fine and for some other runs, it gets stuck as before.  I tried adding wait of few milliseconds to stabilize the test, but it didn't work.
Even cssSelector did not help.

Comment: I am posting the modified Test code below:

`private WebDriver webDriver;

@Test
public void testClickButton() {

webDriver = getFireFoxDriver();

WebElement deleteElement = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text() = 'Delete']"));
Action deleteAction = getActionBuilder().click(deleteElement).build();
deleteAction.perform();

//JAVASCRIPT CONFIRMATION COMES UP. THE TEST STILL GETS STUCK FOR SOME RUNS.
closePopUp();
}`

Thanks once again for all your help.

Comment: Selenium 2.17.0 contains a fix:  * Fixed issue with permissions on windows caused by wrapping
Maybe that helps.